# com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, vaadin

Please can you help with:

```
com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

it crashes `mainLayout.setWidth("100%");`

```
//***************************************
private void createUI() {
    final Window mainWindow = new Window("Raspberry Pi GPIO Control Center");
    VerticalLayout mainLayout = (VerticalLayout) mainWindow.getContent();
    setContent(mainLayout);
    System.out.println("1");
    mainLayout.setWidth("100%");
    System.out.println("2");
    mRefresher = new Refresher();
    mRefresher.setRefreshInterval(RefreshIntervalMilliSec);
    mRefresher.addListener(new RefreshListener() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void refresh(Refresher source) {
            periodicRefresh();
        }
    });
    mainLayout.addComponent(mRefresher);
    createTitle(mainLayout);
    mMainContentLayout = new VerticalLayout();
    mMainContentLayout.setWidth("100%");
    mainLayout.addComponent(mMainContentLayout);
    mainLayout.setComponentAlignment(mMainContentLayout, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
    createUIForUser();
}
//***************************************
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mainWindow.getContent();` returns `null` because the Window has no default layout, so you get a NPE in `mainLayout.setWidth("100%");`

change the line

```
 VerticalLayout mainLayout = (VerticalLayout) mainWindow.getContent();
```

To

```
VerticalLayout content = new VerticalLayout();
```

and it should work.